# How to resolve an IP on a VM that is running on google cloud and Domain is on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-route53

I have a VM hosted on google running a wordpress website and the domain I own is on AWS. I purchased this domain on AWS a while back so it is under AWS ownership. I was wondering if there is a way to have the DNS resolve to my website that is on Google cloud.

I have tried using each cloud providers name servers on each cloud but that hasn't worked. Is there anything i can do with SOA.

Comment: So do you want to point the domain to the Wordpress site on the VM?

Comment: yeah i do. but its hosted on GCP so I can just add a simple routing rule I believe

Comment: Can you access the DNS settings of the domain?

Comment: You can add A record to point the VM IP address

Comment: Ive tired doing that on AWS hosted zone where the domain is, but its not working. Is this something that should work?

Comment: Ah, your domain is on AWS and Wordpress is on GCP?

Comment: Can you get the GCP VP IP address? Then you can add an A record with the IP in AWS route53. If you can create an IAM user, I can do that for you. :)

Comment: Yeah ive tried that. https://imgur.com/icfciMA

Comment: It's not added correctly, or you should wait some time for the record to propagate https://dnschecker.org/#A/digital-story.co

Comment: Do you know anything that could be incorrect about it? i just added simple rule on AWS to the external IP

Comment: NOthing incorrect, I guess. You can wait a while and check it again

Comment: Yeah, i guess ill have to check back tomorrow

Comment: IF it doesn't work tomorrow, we can change the name server to GCP and add the domain records on GCP instead of AWS